# Kile, shortcut for most commonly used WORDS?

Tags: macros, acronyms, kile

I'd like to know how to write a `*.cwl` file for Kile (the LaTeX editor for KDE Debian 7.3) with a list of shortcut words, that I use often such as bcc= because, e--= electrons, h0= holes and so forth. I've read the Kile handbook but it isn't clear on what is the correct formatting.

1. How do I write the cwl file?
2. Where do I save it so that Kile sees it and accepts it?
3. How do I call the different shortcuts while typing in Kile? Spacebar + smth...?

Is there a tutorial or a more detailed guide and examples? I'm looking for something equivalent to the "Macros" feature of TEXStudio.

**EDIT**: I think what I'm looking for are Abbreviations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are indeed abbreviations.

I did a quick search on my linux system and found `example.cwl`:

```
# abbreviation mode: example
# dani/8.1.2004
ba=baseline
bab=babel package
bar=baselineskip rubber length
bdc=book document class
bi=bibliography styles
bip=bibliography style parameters
bs=\backslash
cc=\textsc{CodeCompletion}
kile=KDE integrated LaTeX editor
x=\
T=\TeX
L=\LaTeX
```

I think the format is quite clear: you type the abbreviation followed by a `=` followed by the expanded item. Lines starting with `#` are used for comment.

You install such a file by specifying it in `Settings > Configure Kile... > Complete > Abbreviation`

You can also enable Abbreviation mode. In case the abbreviation should only be expanded occasionally, you hit `Ctrl+Alt+Space` after typing for instance `bip`.